# How to implement cross domain access in tomcat when using only jsp and javascript/ajax/jQuery and not using php?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tomcat, google-api, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a **GIS Map Java web application using jsp**, javascript/ajax/jQuery which is deployed in **tomcat server**. I need to implement **cross-domain access** here to get response from **google api** which return response in json format. But since cross domain access is not possible with `xmlhttp`, I cant get a response.

I have seen some posts suggesting the use of `proxy.php` in client side. But I am not using php and I would like to know if there is anyway to implement this using `jsp/javascript` alone. Is there any special configuration to be set in tomcat?? Kindly help.

Here is what i try to do:

```
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=26.849307092121,75.781290279188&destination=26.932491611988,75.805420139913&alternatives=true&sensor=false";
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send();


           function AJAX_addShortestRoute() {
                //    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                var response=xmlhttp.responseText;
//                document.write(response);
                alert(response);
            }`
```

But the request is never processed, since cross-domain access is not possible. Kindly help

Thanks and Regards
Ginger.

Comment: Why are you using an Ajax call and not their api?

Comment: I am using Openlayers along with google map. I am not sure if both Google api and Openlayers could be used parallely if Openlayers is used to display map.

Comment: I'm not sure "`proxy.php` in client side" is going to help you. Do clients often run PHP servers alongside their web browsers?

Comment: Ya i know its not going to help. that is y i asked if there is any alternative available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. The only solution for cross domain (which I think) is use cross domain access through proxy server..

Here is how it is done.

```
var mapsUrl    = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='+source_y+','+source_x+'&destination='+dest_y+','+dest_x+'&alternatives=true&sensor=true';
var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(mapsUrl);
var proxyUrl   = 'http://jsonp.guffa.com/Proxy.ashx?url=' + encodedUrl;

$.ajax({
    url: proxyUrl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {

         //Your code goes here
    }
});
```